# Получить картинку через запрос

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Есть вот такая простая задача: послать запрос на сервер и скачать, к примеру, определенную картинку в какой-нибудь файл, найдя теги `img` в этом `html` коде. Я вроде понимаю, как в C# можно послать `get`-запрос,получить `html`, просмотреть его на теги `img` и вытащить оттуда параметр `src`, но вот что делать дальше с адресом картинки, не понимаю. Тем более, в моем случае там почему-то не просто адрес, а какой-то еще один `get`-запрос, который указывает параметры картинки типа ширины и высоты. Никогда с такими задачами не сталкивался. Если кто-нибудь скажет, что можно почитать по этому поводу, буду премного благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать WebClient.DownloadFile для загрузки изображения по URL

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

wc.DownloadFile("http://example.com/z.png",@"c:\z.png");
```

Чтобы получить прямую ссылку на скачивание, можно взять какой-нибудь HTML-парсер, например,  [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) и пропарсить HTML.